# Read geometries from ESRI shapefile 'one-by-one'

Tags: java, shapefile, esri

I am trying to achieve simple goal. Using https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java library I want to read **multiple** geometries from shapefile, but so far it seems that API doesn't provide ability to do so, by now I managed to impport single geometry from file (first one).

Here are code samples that I tried in order to make it works:

property in = FileInputStream

```
Geometry geometry = GeometryEngine.geometryFromEsriShape(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), Geometry.Type.Unknown);
System.out.println(geometry);


OperatorImportFromESRIShape importerShape = (OperatorImportFromESRIShape) OperatorFactoryLocal.getInstance().getOperator(Operator.Type.ImportFromESRIShape);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
Geometry geometry = importerShape.execute(0, Geometry.Type.Unknown, byteBuffer);
```

In both cases API returns only single Geometry.
The question is how to read multiple geometries from input stream one by one.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I am struggeling to do the same thing right now. But in my case geometry is always null. What is your input?

Comment: With the "working" version I still get only NULL as a result. What is your input a normal .shp file?

Comment: For more ideas see https://github.com/mraad/Shapefile

Answer (score 0):

When you move your java package to:

```
package com.esri.core.geometry;
```

You can access a package protected Method, that returns a GeometryCursor:

```
buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path_to_Shapefile")));
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
OperatorImportFromESRIShape op = (OperatorImportFromESRIShape) OperatorFactoryLocal.getInstance().getOperator(
        Type.ImportFromESRIShape);
SimpleByteBufferCursor byteBufferCursor = new SimpleByteBufferCursor(buffer);
GeometryCursor geometryCursor = op.execute(ShapeImportFlags.ShapeImportNonTrusted, Geometry.Type.Unknown,
        byteBufferCursor);
Geometry cursor;
while ((cursor = geometryCursor.next()) != null) {
  System.out.println(cursor);
}
```

Comment: I tried similar code and it didn't work for me, also I can clearly see in this test https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/esri/core/geometry/TestImportExport.java that it expects ByteBuffer per shape and ByteBufferCursor should contain multiple ByteBuffers per shape to iterate through them, otherwise it itertates only once, did you really tested this solution?

Comment: nope, not really. As said I always get NULL for my shapefile. I just made the code "run" and hoped that you would tell me what input you had. Your geometry was != null, I suppose. I am currently using http://sourceforge.net/projects/javashapefilere/, which at least reads my shapefile.

Comment: ok, thank you for reply, if I comment out this line buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); it reads single Geometry but I am not sure that it is correct, so it doesn't work for now